# Charging SLA using step down converter?

Tags: batteries, solar-cell

I have a 10w solar panel which outputs about 17V 0.5A at full sunlight. I use a small buck converter to charge my SLA 7.2Ah battery. I have currently set the buck converter output voltage to 14v and in the day time it charges the battery and at night I use the battery to power a 10w led (which uses about 9.5W with the fan on). Battery charges at about 0.5A when there is full sun light.

My questions are,

1. 14V is the best voltage to charge the battery on CV or I should change the voltage of buck converter ?
2. Is it okay to charge a SLA battery using this method even if I used a power supply to charge it?  (power supply ------buck converter------battery)
3. Is it okay to leave the battery charging at 14v for longer periods of time in case if I dont use the battery at night to power the light ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main battery usage modes

- **In cyclic use** where you take substantial energy every or most days
  it is OK to **charge to 14 to 15 volts.**

  **This is how you usually use the battery.**
  .
- For **standby or float use** with no regular deep discharge
  charge to 13.5 - 13.8 volts.
  This applies when the battery remains fully or almost full charged with no daily deep discharge.

Below I'll use 13.8/14.5 as the target for float/cyclic mode charging.

---

14 to 15 Volt is acceptable for cyclic use.

If you are floating the battery for some time without discharge then typically 13.5 - 13.8 float Voltage is recommended.

---

If you can get 17V x 0.5A the a buck converter should get 14V at 17/14 * 0.5A x Z/100
where z is % efficiency. If you are getting 0.5A in and 0.5A out as you state (which may just have been an approximation) then Z = 82% - and a piece of wire would work as well.

A reasonable buck converter should be able to achieve 90% efficiency giving about 0.55A at 14V out for about 17V at 0.5A in.

At lower battery voltages the buck converter is probably worth using.

PV panels will provide more current when loaded beyond they maximum power point (Wmp) and it **may** be that by connecting the panel directly to the battery (via a diode) you would get more current than by using the buck converter. This is not certain but is easily tried. The advantage of the buck converter is that it limits Vbattery_max to a preset voltage (eg here = say 13.8V/14.5V, while a direct diode connection from PV panel to battery will overcharge the battery if no means is provided to limit voltage rise.

For best use of the available energy you can run the charger in a CC/CV mode where it provides as much current as possible (CC mode nominally) until the battery reaches say 13.8V/14.5V and then changes to CV mode and hold the voltage at 13.8V/14.5V and the battery takes "what it wants".

An easyish way to run the buck converter in CC mode is to set the output voltage just high enough above the battery voltage that the battery accepts all available charge, until the battery reaches 13.8V (for float mode) or 14.5 - 15 volts for cyclic mode.
A simple way to do this is to use a target voltage a diode drop above vbattery. So eg if Vbattery = 12V Vtarget = 12V + VF_diode = say 12V + 0.6V = 12.6V. As long as the battery accepts all available current at that voltage the converter is operating at near optimum Vout. When Vbattery reaches 13.8V  (or 14.5V) the target voltage is clamped at 13.8V/14.5 .

**______________**

**Example of loading a panel below MPP to get higher current.**

**This shows that for the example panel - which is NOT the user's panel - direct connection of panel to battery may be more efficient than using a 90% efficient buck converter!**. Actual panel in use and converter performance need to be checked.

The diagram below is a curve from an existing panel with Vmp ~= 35V and Imp ~= 8.6V.
I have added X axis labelling for an ~= Vmp=17V panel amd Y axis can be scaled proportionately if desired. Your panel may not have exactly the same V/I/Power curves but these are typical.

The dashed curves are power out at 3 insolation levels. Say 100%, 75% and 50% of full sun - not important.
Blue vertical lines drop from the peak of eac power curve (Wmp) to the relevant VI curve touching then at current-at-peak-power = Imp.
The horizontal red lines to the Y axis allow the current Imp to be read.
Units are 1-10 but can be adapted to the existing panel if desired.
The green vertical line is a load of ~= 12V. (maybe 12.3).
The orange lines show the panel current at 12V. 
Y axis current figures are rough as the scaale has been hacked about somewhat in editing.

It can be seen that for 100% insolation Imp ~= 8.6A but I12V ~= 9.2A.
At 75% insolation figures are 7.1A / 7.6A
At 50% insolation figures are 5.5A / 5.8A.

So:
100% 9.2/8.6 = +7%
 75% 7.6/7.1 = +8.5%
 50% 5.8/5.5 = + 5.5%

SO without any controller, current to a 12V load would be increased beyond Imp by 5.5% y 8.5% above Imp by just supplying the battery directly by the PV panel.

With a buck converter  Icharge = Vpv/Vbattery x Ipv x %_buck_efficiency/100

If a good efficiency buck converter was used (say 90% efficient) then at 12V battery

100% insolation Vpv=14V, Ipv = 8.6, Icharge (90%)= 9.03A = lower than direct connection.

50% insolation Vpv = 13.75V, Ipv = 5.5A, Icharge = 5.7A = lower than direct connection.

How this compares to the panel under consideration needs to be checked.
At much higher Vpanel:Vbattery ratios a 90% buck converter is easily superior. 
A 95% efficient buck converter should have a slight 'edge'

[image]

---

IMPORTANT

The Imp line must be drawn as shown here.
The apparently flat top of the curve is misleading.

[image]

Comment: So you mean that the panel will provide more current if I connect the panel directly to the battery?  I thought the panel amperage stays the same even if the voltage of the panel lowers....... So less VxA means lower watts..... Am I wrong here?... And my battery charges at about 0.55A as u stated. I just rounded it up to 0.5A bevause I didn't think that it would be that important :)... Currently, I run the buck converter at 14v all the time. It's 0.2V more than 13.8V so that's not that bad for the battery right ?

Comment: @IshanFdo1 Panel I increases as the panel load gets heavier (smaller R). Current at max power (Imp) is about 85%-95% of Isc (I short circuit. If you take a panel with Vmp = 17V say and clamp it at say 13V or 14V or ... then I will be > Imp and < Isc. Exactly where on the curve it lies will vary with battery and panel specs. Look at any PV panel VI curves to check that  what I am saying is OK. | eg [This curve set](http://solarpowerplanetearth.com/images/Solar_IV_curve.jpg) can be scaled to match the current specs. Looks like the buck converter wins very slightly at higher battery voltages

Comment: So a final answer. If I cycle my battery everyday is it okay to charge at 14v?  (it rarely gets to 14v in one day. The day ends with about 13v charge)

Comment: @IshanFdo1 Yes. In fact higher is OK. My answer mentioned cyclic and standby modes and the relevant maximum voltages BUT on looking back I see I did not make the distinction clear enough overall. || In cyclic use where you take substantial power every or most days it is OK to charge to 14 to 15 volts. This is how you usually use the battery. | For standby or float use with no regular deep discharge use 13.5 - 13.8 volts.

Comment: Okay, so I will just charge it to 14v just to be safe :) another simple question, what will happen if I use a power supply and then charge the battery at 14v for a very long time ? Like 24hours, will the battery stop drawing current when it's fully charged or will it keep drawing current? and is it safe to keep it on 14v for about 24hrs continuously ?(and after 24hr I will start cycling the battery again)

Comment: @IshanFdo1 I have update (hopefully improved) my answer. Note that above 14.5V (approaching 15V) is OK in cycle mode and especially if you are taking a lot of energy. 14V or 14.5V is OK for 24 hr charge. The battery manufacturer will specify Imax for cycle mode - probably about 2A MAX. If you hold voltage at say 14.5V the battery will draw less and less current and then stop. Occasionally it is desirable to "boost charge" the battery to 15V+ for a short period (maybe 1 hour) to get all cells charged fully and evenly but not usually. For interest, where are you located?

Comment: @IshanFdo1 - VERY important for battery life - how long do you operate the LED for each night? What does the battery voltage fall to?

Comment: I live in Sri Lanka. Room temp is around 30c. I can run the LED for about 3hrs with a full day of charge. I connect the LED and the voltage drops to about 12.3v and then I disconnect the LED when the voltage hits about 10.7V because the data sheet states that the low voltage of the battery is 10.5v when it's connected to small loads. Edit : battery is Motoma 7.0ah 12v battery, if I ever it correctly the model name is ms12v7... Not entirely sure about the model number )

Comment: If you want your battery to have a long(er)  lifetime you cannot discharge it my more than about 50% of its full capacity. Ideally you want a battery made for "deep discharge" use and even then probably 50% max discharge is wise. Full deep discharge cycles of an ordinary lead acid battery will destroy it in 100-200 cycles. Sadly.

Comment: Destroy means?  it will stop working all of a sudden?  or will it just lose capacity very fast? This is my spare battery from an old ups so I would like to experiment on it :D I will try using it in full deep discharges and see if it really degrades very fast

Comment: @IshanFdo1 Lose capacity rapidly. I've heard of some batteries lasting 50 cycles if especially heavily abused.

Comment: Okay! thanks for the info you answered all the questions that I had and I learned a new thing that the solar panels I goes up and the V goes down :) thanks for the help. Really appreciate it :)))

Comment: I think I dont understand the More I when lower V thing, according to this graph the current doesnt seem to go up when the Voltage goes down of the solar panel. http://pveducation.org/sites/default/files/PVCDROM/Solar-Cell-Operation/Images/IV-ISC.gif because of that the power from the cell also goes down. Thats why we need a MPPT solar controller for large solar panels right ? Am I mistaken or are u mistaken ?

Comment: @IshanFdo1 Please see added worked example. Real panels DO increase in output I as load increases and V drops. This varies with panel used and needs to be checked in a given case. Note that lower efficiency panels with a lower "fill factor" have a greater gain this way than higher efficiency panels. Fill factor = Vmp x Imp/Voc x Isc. Hizh Z cells droop less when loaded. So cheap cells usually show better gains when used directly as above.